# Python pandas search in DataFrame MultiIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, search, multi-index

This is what I do:

```py
import pandas as pd
t = pd.DataFrame(data={'i1':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                       'i2':[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3],
                       'x':[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.,10.,11.,12.]})
t.set_index(['i1','i2'], inplace=True)
t.sort_index(inplace=True)
t.index.values.searchsorted( (1,1) )
```

This is the error I get:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
> <module> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and
> 'int'
```

Please, help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

Index values are tuples: `type(t.index.values[0])` gives correctly `<class 'tuple'>` and I give as input to `searchsorted` a tuple. So where does the 'tuple' to 'int' comparison come from?

```
>>> print(t)
          x
i1 i2      
0  0    1.0
   1    2.0
   2    3.0
   3    4.0
1  0    5.0
   1    6.0
   2    7.0
   3    8.0
2  0    9.0
   1   10.0
   2   11.0
   3   12.0
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output in my example is 5 (the position of the searched for index value in the index array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```py
>>> t.index.get_loc( (1,1) )
5
```

This solution is ~200 times faster that using `t.index.get_indexer`:

```py
>>> import time
>>> time.clock()
168.56
>>> for i in range(10000): a = t.index.get_indexer([(1,1)])[0]
... 
>>> time.clock()
176.76
>>> (176.76 - 168.56) / 10000
0.0008199999999999989 # 820e-6 sec per call
>>> time.clock()
176.76
>>> for i in range(1000000): a = t.index.get_loc( (1,1) )
... 
>>> time.clock()
180.94
>>> (180.94-176.76)/1000000
4.1800000000000066e-06 # 4.2e-6 sec per call
```

Answer (score 1):

`searchsorted` doesn't work with tuples. There's an open issue on github for [Multiarray searchsorted fails](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14833)

On that issue, one of the participants suggests using [`get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.1/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html)

With your code

```
t.index.get_indexer([(1,1)])[0]
# outputs:
5
```